# Find the sum of the following series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+m)}$

Tags: telescopic-series

I am suppose to find the sum of
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+m)}$

But after using partial fractions and getting $ \frac 1m
 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} -\frac{1}{n+m}$

then i couldnt figure out what to do

Comment: Which terms don't cancel?

Comment: i tried setting n=1,2,3 but couldn't find  terms that cancel each other

Comment: Compute the partial sum first.

Comment: What is the answer when $m=1$?  What about $m=2$?

Answer (score 3):

For some reason, the site wont allow me to comment. But anyways, a supposed hint would be, if;
$$f(m)= \frac 1m
 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} -\frac{1}{n+m}$$
This would just be; (As this is a telescoping sum)
$$f(m)=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{n=1}^m \frac{1}{n}$$

Plugging in the value of $m=3$, you get
$$f(3)=\frac{1}{3}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}\right)$$

Comment: You have to have a certain reputation on the site before you can comment.  I don't remember what the minimum is, but I've upvoted your post, so you're on your way.  Welcome to MSE.

Comment: Hey thanks, kind of weird they let me answer but not comment.

Comment: It's just a matter of making sure you're acculturated to the site.  You'll find there are other things you can't do until you get more rep.  If you edit a post, your edits will have to be approved before they're posted.  You also won't be able to upload images directly.  (Include a link to the image, and someone will post it for you.)  As you use the site, I think it will become clear why these rules are in place.

Answer (score 1):

I'll do $m=3$. Then $m=3$ times the sum is then
$$\left(\frac11-\frac14\right)
+\left(\frac12-\frac15\right)
+\left(\frac13-\frac16\right)
+\left(\frac14-\frac17\right)+\cdots.
$$
The brackets three apart telescope, leaving just
$$\frac11+\frac12+\frac13.$$

Answer (score 1):

Use the telescopic summation: $$H_x=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+x} \right)= x \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+x)}$$ See

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number

So the required sum is nothing but $\frac{H_m}{m}.$ where $H_m$ are Harmonic numbers.